# How to fix 'non-nullable property' warning in ASP.NET Razor Pages application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, non-nullable

> Warning    CS8618  Non-nullable property 'Categories_List' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the property as nullable.    RazorPageDemoYoutube    D:\ASP.NET\RazorPage\RazorPageDemo\RazorPageDemoYoutube\Pages\Admin\Categories\Index.cshtml.cs  16  Active

[image]

Comment: In constructor just do Categories_List= new List<Category>

Comment: You can use the `?` suffix to declare a nullable reference type.  Try to add `?` ,like  `public IEnumerable<Category>? Categories_List { get; set; }` .

Comment: The Warning includes the answer to your question How to fix: *Consider declaring the property as nullable.*

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `?` ,like :

```
public IEnumerable<Category>? Categories_List { get; set; }
```

OR:

```
public IEnumerable<Category> Categories_List { get; set; } = new List<Category>();
```

Comment: @Amila Praneeth I use this way to avoid this warning. Is your problem solved ?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the property to the default.

```
public IEnumerable<Category> Categories_List { get; set; } = default!;
```